# __darwin_size_t equivalent to in c#

Tags: c#, objective-c, binding, xamarin

I am writing interfaces of objective-c class so that objective C methods can be called from my C# code. in the objective-c class they have used "__darwin_size_t"

```
#ifndef _SIZE_T 
#define _SIZE_T 
typedef __darwin_size_t        size_t; 
#endif  /* _SIZE_T */
```

from the above code I can understand that  __darwin_size_t is some datatype and "size_t" name can be used for same in this project. I am writing interface in C# language so I need to use some similar datatype that is available in c#. somewhere after this I found a bit more code like bellow

```
#if defined(__SIZE_TYPE__)
typedef __SIZE_TYPE__       __darwin_size_t;    /* sizeof() */
#else
typedef unsigned long       __darwin_size_t;    /* sizeof() */
#endif
```

So I think I can use UInt64 (unsigned long) data type for size_t and Int64 for long long in my c# code.

Please suggest.

Thanks
Vishnu Sharma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion was fine in the bottom part of my question. I think very few people are working on Xamarin cross platform development tool right now.

Vishnu